# Why is LIMIT 1 causing MySQL to timeout in this situation?

Tags: mysql, performance, timeout

We're currently dealing with a slow query in an odd situation. The issue comes into play when we `LIMIT` the results by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, but it works with **any other** limits. This issue is also limited to this one specific user. We can't reproduce the slowness/timeouts with any other user.

We can change the `ORDER BY` to use a different column, and the query works. We can remove the `LIMIT 1`, and the query works. Once we change the `LIMIT` to anything between 1-6, it timesout.

We could get away with setting the `ORDER BY` on a different column, but this may cause reporting issues in the future and doesn't address the 'why' is this happening.

The query:

```
SELECT
         *
        FROM
            table_name tn 
        WHERE
            tn.user = '123'
        ORDER BY
            timestamp_col DESC
        LIMIT 1
```

And our data:

```
user --- timestamp_col --- 
123      2005-02-23 02:02:34
123      2005-03-21 00:12:30
123      2006-01-09 14:23:48
123      2006-01-10 15:01:05
123      2006-01-20 13:11:13
123      2006-10-20 20:08:00
123      2006-11-01 18:31:03
123      2006-12-01 09:10:12
```

Are there special needs when ordering by a `timestamp`?

Comment: Please add the execution plan for both situations (the output of `explain select ...` for the working and the non-working query, e.g. with limit 1 and with limit 7).

Answer (score 1):

Add the composite

```
INDEX(user, timestamp_col)
```

That way both the `WHERE`, the `ORDER BY`, and the `LIMIT` are all handled by the index.  And it will stop after getting the desired `LIMIT`.

Any single-column index needs to read lots of rows and/or sort those rows.